# Sklearn PCA Calculation Seems to Use Truncated Division as Opposed to Floating Point Division

Tags: python, pca, scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction, pandas

I am working with the following dataset:

[Housing dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data)

From this dataset, I am only interested in the following columns: **GrLivArea** (independent variable), and **SalePrice** (dependent variable).

What I want to do is to essentially manually calculate the slope of the PCA line in two dimensions. I know from some reading around that I can use the following formula for the slope.

[image]

I also know that I can use the PCA function from Sklearn to quickly get the slope as well.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# function from exercise solutions
def orthogonal_regression (U,V):   
    """
    The input parameters are the two uncentered arrays U and V respectively 
    containg the x and y coordinates of the data points

    Start by centering the arrays
    """
    U         = U-np.mean(U)
    V         = V-np.mean(V)
    U2        = np.multiply(U,U)
    V2        = np.multiply(V,V)
    UV        = np.multiply(U,V)

    U2sum     = np.sum (U2)
    V2sum     = np.sum (V2)
    UVsum     = np.sum (UV)

    Term1     = V2sum-U2sum
    Term2     = Term1 * Term1
    Term3     = 4. * UVsum * UVsum
    Slope     = (Term1+np.sqrt(Term2+Term3))/(2.*UVsum)

    return Slope

# load data
houses = pd.read_csv(path + 'Houseprices.csv')

# method 1
X = houses['GrLivArea']
y = houses['SalePrice']

# method 2
xy = houses[['GrLivArea', 'SalePrice']].values

print('check the difference between vectors:', 'GrLivArea:', np.sum(xy[:, 0] - X), 'SalePrice:', np.sum(xy[:, 1] - y), '\n')
print('compare first 3 values of GrLivArea before scaling:', xy[:, 0][:3], X.values[:3], '\n')
print('compare the types before scaling:', xy[:, 0].dtype, X.dtype, xy[:, 1].dtype, y.dtype, '\n')

xy[:, 0] = xy[:, 0] / 1000.
X = X / 1000.

xy[:, 1] = xy[:, 1]/100000.
y = y / 100000.

print('compare first 3 values of GrLivArea after scaling:', xy[:, 0][:3], X.values[:3], '<===== WEIRD \n')
print('compare the types after scaling:', xy[:, 0].dtype, X.dtype, xy[:, 1].dtype, y.dtype, '<===== ALSO WEIRD \n')
print('compare function values', orthogonal_regression(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1]), orthogonal_regression(X, y), '<===== MISMATCH \n')
```

Something interesting happens when I run this code. Here is the ouput:

[image]

Depending on how I set up my X and y (method 1 or method 2), I get a different result due to the scaling even though I scale them exactly the same way. At this point I would expect method 1 to be more accurate of the two and match that in Sklearn as it does not truncate.

However, if I run the following code to generate the Sklearn output:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca    = PCA (n_components=1)
pca.fit  (xy) 

slope_pca = pca.components_[0,1]/pca.components_[0,0]
print (slope_pca)
```

The output is:

> 1.7280...

Now my question is, why is this the case? Why does Sklearn not match the non-truncated scaled numbers? It seems Sklearn is doing truncated division somewhere which should not be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sklean` has no fault in this. The numpy array you use has data type `int64`, so when you divide by a number and save back to the same numpy array, the values are converted to integers. To prevent it, just use the following casting:

```
xy = houses[['GrLivArea', 'SalePrice']].values.astype(np.float)
```